# Catching all classes and IDs from a CSS Stylesheet that contain a certain search term

Tags: css, regex

I am using a WordPress premium theme that has a 25.000+ lines styles.css. I want to change the font and main color sitewide, and for this I would like to catch ALL classes and IDs that use them for my childtheme.

Manually searching through 25.000 lines and then selecting and copying the classes together is a very slow procedure, and I am sure this can be automated with RegEx and the preg match all thing or the like, but I know too little about creating such a script.

But at least I could figure out the logic that a script for such a task would need to follow.

So let's say I need a rule that collects ALL classes and IDs to which the font Roboto is assigned.

Basically it needs to
1. find Roboto, then
2. go back to the { and
3. collect everything before { until
4. the last } before, so it needs to go backwards searching
5. This it needs to do through the whole document, to catch all classes to which Roboto is assigned.

The result will be a very big list of comma-separated classes which I can then easily assign the new font to.

Does any of the RegEx experts see the string already in front of his eyes? I am sure it is not that difficult for someone who "speaks" RegEx fluently, but I got soon lost trying to learn it myself, I only succeeded in simple replacments.

```
...
last CSS rule ending here.
}

.some,
.classes,
.and,
#IDs to collect them all,
#not only from this one css rule,
. but from a whole 25.000+lines stylesheet

{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: ... 
  etc.
}
...
```

Comment: 25,000 lines of CSS!!

Comment: Here is just [some crazy regex](https://regex101.com/r/bW2rO8/1) for you that will help you understand you should not be using it for this task: `^\s*([^{\n]+?)\n*(\{[^}]*?font-family:\s*['"]?Roboto\b['"]?[^}]*?\})`.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I dont understand why it is crazy (yes it is very long but I was sure it needs to be to target this task) and why I should not use it? It already nearly does what I need, just that now it is only catching one line before the {, while it should catch all until the last } before. Can this be as well done? Maybe you can explain to me in more detail why such a script as I search for should not be possible or at least not be done with regex? I would run this script not on websites, it is just a one-time help to extract all classes that then are used in a child CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way of targeting all classes with a specific *CSS Rule* like `font-family` either with *CSS*, *JavaScript*, or *jQuery*

But, you can do searches for:

> 'begins with..'

```
div[class^="something"] { } /* target divs */
*[class^="something"] { } /* targets everything */

div[id^="something"] { } /* target divs */
*[id^="something"] { } /* targets everything */
```

which would work on something like this:-

```
<div class="something-else-class"></div>
```

> 'contains..'

```
div[class*="something"] { }
```

which would work on

```
<div class="is-something-here"></div> 
<!-- class name can be anything. "something" can be anywhere -->
```

> 'ends with...'

```
div[class$="something"] { }
```

which would work on

```
<div class="you-are-something"></div>
```

This way you can target all classes and/or id's that have a `font-family` *Rule* and change it.

**Reference**

- [CSS3 Attribute Selectors: Substring Matching](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css3-attribute-selectors-substring-matching/)

Comment: Yes, thanks for sharing, this is very good to know. I just don't get the bridge to my need, because how should I target all classes with Roboto font in it? They would need to have similarities to catch them with this method, but they have very different names.